# Java 8: Create tuples from Java List

Tags: java, hashmap

I am looking to use Java 8s new features to create key value pairs from a Java list and insert into a map

Consider this list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I am looking for 2 tuples, `[1, 2]` and `[3, 4]`

This is my code, the idea of which I copied from an answer to a similar question

Where am I going wrong? Nothing is added to the map.

```
IntStream.range(1, list.size())
        .filter(i -> i + 1 % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(list.get(i - 1), list.get(i)))
        .forEach(entry -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have entered to common Java 8 pitfall: you have created the stream, described how you want to process it, but didn't triggered it to be processed.

After `mapToObj` call you should trigger the processing via calling method `collect`, to lets say a `List`, and then make `forEach` call. Or directly use  `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`:

```
IntStream.range(1, list.size())
            .filter(i -> (i + 1) % 2 == 0)
            .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(list.get(i - 1), list.get(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(o -> o.getKey(), o -> o.getValue()))
```

Comment: and I guess in filter better write `(i + 1) % 2 == 0`

Comment: You should update your answer with this.  I believe the % happens first so the filter will filter out every item leaving an empty stream.

Comment: It looks to me like the (i + 1) not being in brackets was the cause above, as far as I can tell the forEach works fine